# Read flag when a message is read by the user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Editing the question...

I figured out how can the chat be made in sync but in order to do that I need to send a read flag to the database. It's easy to send a **delivered** flag but how can I send a flag when the message is **read** by the recipient.

Comment: This is way too broad for SO, you likely want to narrow in your questions(split them up, which will also help you) :)

Comment: Exactly the same way you send the delivered flag, but when the user reads the message... ;)

Comment: I guess I have to put an event when a message is **opened**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do the same. I have put an event when any conversation is opened and the event sends the status as read.